# Copying an array of directory contents into a single directory using Gradle

Tags: gradle

In our build, we have these "component" directories. Subprojects use different sets of components, and the contents of these components must be copied into the build directory. So, imagine each subproject defines the list of included components as: `project.ext.components = ['aaa', 'bbb', 'ccc']`. These exist in a directory (from project root) like `components/aaa`, `components/bbb`, etc. I want to copy the *contents* of each directory into the project's `build` directory.

Basically, if I had to translate this to UNIX, I'd be doing a series of copies like:

```
cp -R components/aaa/* build/
cp -R components/bbb/* build/
cp -R components/ccc/* build/
```

What's a good way to do this?

I could loop over `project.ext.components` in a task and use the `copy` closure, but how would I define the task inputs/outputs? The task won't be a `Copy` type task, but just a normal task with a `doFirst`, a loop in that, and `copy` closures, so we don't get the inputs/outputs defined for us for free like we would with a `Copy` task.

I see in the [Copy DSL](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.Copy.html) that there's an `includes` property that seems promising, but I can't really figure out a way to get it to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
task copy(type: Copy) {
    into buildDir
    components.each {
        from "components/$it"
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. This solves the original question. But I do have a follow-up... what if I want to preserve the "components" part of the path? In other words, after copying, I want there to be a `build/components/aaa` directory.

Comment: `into buildDir; components.each { name -> into("components/$name") { from "components/$name" } }`.

Comment: Ah, makes sense. Didn't know `into` could be a closure. Thanks!

Comment: Side note: I had trouble getting this to work because I thought the `name ->` part was unnecessary and I could just use `it` instead. But it's very necessary because the `from` closure changes was `it` is. And the learning continues...

Comment: A good rule of thumb is to only use `it` for one-liners. Otherwise it quickly gets confusing.